# Add and remove checkboxes for QTreeWidgetItems

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

My app is written with PyQt5.
I have a QTreeWidget with some elements:

```
Parent
--Child 1
--Child 2
```

I want to add and remove checkboxes to child elements dynamically. I managed to add the checkboxes with

```
item.setFlags(item.flags() | 16)
```

and

```
item.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

But I have 2 problems:

I can't remove those checkboxes. I tried resetting the flags but the checkbox is still there, only disabled. I also cant use stylesheets because I cant .setStyleSheet for a single treeWidgetItem. How can I remove it?

and I don't want that.

Minimal example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt5 import QtCore
app = QApplication([])
label = QTreeWidget()
label.show()
parent = QTreeWidgetItem(label)
parent.setText(0, "Parent")

child1 = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
child1.setText(0, "child1")

child2 = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
child2.setText(0, "child2")

child1.setFlags(child1.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
child1.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Checked)

child1.setFlags(child1.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)


app.exec_()
```

Changing the ItemIsUserCheckable flag back doesn't remove the checkbox.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, thank you for your answer. I've added the minimal example, switching the flag off doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not place

```
item.setFlags(item.flags() | 16)
```

as it is not readable, it is better to use

```
item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
```

Going to the problem, if you want to remove the checkbox then you have to remove that flag:

```
item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole, None)
```

The delegate to do the painting does not take into account the flag associated with the QModelIndex, so as [@musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) points out, the state must also be cleared by setting None.

Comment: I'd like to add that, even after setting the check state to Unchecked, the checkbox is still visible, since the delegate paints it no matter if the flag isn't set. In order to completely remove the checkbox, the CheckStateRole has to be cleared: `item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole, None)`.